# solr - can I use it for this?

Tags: solr

Is solr just for searching ie it's not for 'updating' or 'inserting' data?

My site is currently MySQL based, and on looking at SOLR as an alt option, I see you make your queries through http requests.

My first thought was - how do you stop someone from making a query that updates or inserts data?

Obviously, I'm not understanding SOLR, hence my question here.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solr mainly is for Full Text search, and rather should not be used as a Persistent store.
Solr stores its data in the File store and does not provide the features of Relational database (ACID or Nested Entities etc )
Usually, the model followed is use Relationship database for you data management.
Replicate the data into Solr for Full Text search.
You can always control the Insert/Update access for Solr by securing the urls.

Comment: Thanks Jayendra - that throws some light over it mate.